# Regex for a conditional replace

Tags: java, regex

Would like to replace all:

```
"<br />" (br tags)
```

with either:
    `" "` if there are no spaces surrounding the tag
or
    `""` if there is at least one adjacent space

Examples: a`<br/>`b -> a_b, a`<br/>`__b -> a__b   (using _ for space)

Using Java

Comment: I have a feeling you are looking for HTML parser.

Comment: Why not just replace with " " always?

Comment: Please stop to use regular expression to parse & modify the html content.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable use of regex with HTML. OP isn't trying to parse the document or anything here. It's a simple, find some arbitrary string and replace it.

Comment: @Syon: Ah, good, that was a close one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in Java:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("(?<!\\s)<br>(?!\\s)|<br>\\s|\\s<br>", " ");
```

#### Online Regex Demo

Comment: change it as per OP inputs `<br />`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem I stated.  If there were already 5 spaces they would get replaced with a single space.  I want to preserve the original spacing and just remove the br.  The space should be inserted only if no spaces exist.

Comment: See updated answer and demo link. If it works out well then please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Nice work, +1 :) @Art, According to the iron laws of SO etiquette, I'm allowed to [tell someone who has never accepted an answer about how it works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/). :) If this or another answer works, would you consider clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer to say you accepted it? That's how the reputation system works here, accepting an answer gives reputation both to the answerer and to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Java

```
String inputStr  = "<br/> bla bla <br />"
String outputStr = inputStr.replaceAll(\\s*<br\\s*/>\\s*", "");
System.out.println(outputStr);
```

Output:

```
bla bla
```

Regex Explanation :
[image]